# Strange results from Magento search (mini)

Tags: search, magento

I have some strange results from my mini search. Hardly any products are retrieved. Just a few. I've updated the index, cleared the cache manually, all that. I've had a look at catalogsearch_fulltext and it all seems to be there. And in the autocomplete dropdown I will see the correct number, for example if I type: "Frank" I will get "Frank Sinatra (7)" implying 7 results.

But alas, it will come back with only one. Or none, depending on the search.

I've also tried the different search options (like, fulltext, combined). Nothing seems to change the results coming back.

Where do I look next?
Any help would be seriously appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

please check your attributes, see: catalog -> attributes -> manage attributes

select the tab searchable and filter it on yes.

Check these attributes and make sure they all have yes in "use in quick search" and "use in advanced search"

If you need more attributes to use in the search (maybe some you have created) find them, and do the same on those.

Reindex you catalog search index.

If this dosent help, wee need to know if there has been made changes in your magento installation.